# How do I tell what the datasource is for a rdlc report?

Tags: winforms, rdlc

I'm working with a C#, .net, WinForms project with a RDLC report that I've inherited.  How do I tell what class is used for the report?

I've looked under DataSources, but it lists all the datasources (class names) for the entire project, not just this report.  I've looked under properties for the report, but see nothing.  The properties for the Tablix say the DataSetName is "DataSet1", but that doesn't tell me anything and I don't see "DataSet1" listed under the DataSources tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you can create a RDLC report from a `DataSet` and the delete it; this is not recommended because if you need to add a field to the report you need to recreate the entire `DataSet`.

In order to better understand report datasource, you can open the .rdlc file in notepad and analyze `Datasets` tag.

```
<DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
        <Fields>
            <Field Name="Column1">
                <DataField>Column1</DataField>
                <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="Column2">
                <DataField>Column2</DataField>
                <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
            </Field>
            <Field Name="Column3">
                <DataField>Column3</DataField>
                <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
        <Query>
            <DataSourceName>DataSet1</DataSourceName>
            <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
        </Query>
        <rd:DataSetInfo>
            <rd:DataSetName>DataSet1</rd:DataSetName>
            <rd:SchemaPath>C:\TEST\DataSet1.xsd</rd:SchemaPath>
            <rd:TableName>Table1</rd:TableName>
            <rd:TableAdapterFillMethod />
            <rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod />
            <rd:TableAdapterName />
        </rd:DataSetInfo>
    </DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

Answer (score 0):

To view the data sources and data sets within report designer, do

CTRL + ALT + D

[image]

Within this, it shows your data sources.  It could be a DataSet (multiple tables queried and supplied as one entire "set" of tables for the report.  It could also exist as an object-based data source such as a class with Collection/Lists of things that are being reported.

The DataSets portion where I show "OneTableWithinDataSet" is indicating one such table used in the report.  You could have a report with multiple table.column fields being presented. However, a report Tablix control is typically bound to a single primary "Table" and all records displayed are associated with that.

If your system has changed, such as data being prepared and you now have new columns and such, you should be able to right-click the data source and individual tables and "Refresh" them.  If your schema is not updated, you may have to do that.

In the framework of running reports that I created, before running said report based on tables queried from a database, I would always do a fresh dump of the XML/XSD schema to an output folder.  So when changes DID happen, I could just copy whatever was latest into production source XML/XSD location, rebuild the project.  Then I could do the "Refresh" on the report and the new columns would appear for me to utilize.